# How can add a post on a/this open SourceForge forum thread?

Tags: sourceforge

How can I add a post to this or any SourceForge thread like this?

https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuwin32/bugs/241/

The status is open and I am logged in but I can't see a reply option.

I don't want to create a new thread so I'm not clicking the *create new ticket* button.

**Added example:**

Here is a [**LINK**](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuwin32/bugs/242/) to another example. Somebody added to it in May 2015 even though it was created in 2005, so it's not too old to comment on.

Comment: At first I thought it was perhaps the age of that ticket (10+ years old) although there seems to be something "restricting" discussion on all tickets for that _project_? You would normally expect to see a comment box at the end of the discussion list?

Comment: @w3d  yeah.. I added another example,    somebody posted in may 2015 so it's not too old for it. but still no option.  https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuwin32/bugs/242/